# Visibility of recommendations on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

I have a profile on LinkedIn with a few recommendations from others. When I view my own profile, I can see the recommendations. I have been performing a few tests and, apparently,

- if someone who's a direct connection views my profile, they can see the recomendations on my profile.
- If someone who has a LinkedIn profile, but it's not a direct connection of mine, visits my profile, **they can't see the recommendations**.
- If someone who doesn't own a LinkedIn profile, or is logged out, visits my profile page, they also **can't see the recommendations**.

In my opinion, a key point for building a great linkedin profile is to get goot recommendations, but what is the point if potential employers can't see it?!

Or I'm making some mistake and there's a setting somewhere to publicly enable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, in order for people to see your recommendations, they must be a first connection. All others can see the number of recommendations you have, but that is it.

My suggestion to you would be to connect with the recruiters and individuals that you want to see your profile.  That is the best solution.

Also, LinkedIn gives you an option that will allow you to export your profile to a PDF.  If you do this, you will have a hard copy of your profile that will include your recommendations.

Steps to export

1. Go to "Profile"
2. "View Profile"
3. In your header area, click on the drop down arrow next to the "Edit" button
4. Click on "Export to PDF"